# Intellisense errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've made a modular application and each module is a separate project, they are of similar appearance to MVC areas.

I implemented a custom `WebViewPage` but even after removing the pointer from `web.config` back to default the intellisense is still dysfunctional.

On the first line of my razor view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Module2.Models.TestModel>
```

I get the warning:

> *xxx\Module2\Views\Shared\TestModelTable.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type
>   WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following
>   error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation..  xxx\Module2\Views\Shared\TestModelTable.cshtml*

And the error:

> *The name 'model' does not exist in the current context   xxx\Module2\Views\Shared\TestModelTable.cshtml*

Then each time I try to reference the model an error appears:

> *The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   xxx\Module2\Views\Shared\TestModelTable.cshtml  26  14  Module2*

Additionally if I add `ViewBag.Title` to the view I get this error:

> *One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a
>   reference?    xxx\Module2\Views\Shared\TestModelTable.cshtml*

I would assume there was is a problem with the web configs but they are standard web configs found in mvc areas (I removed the custom `WebPageView`)

This happens for every view I try to create in each module, however the main application works fine. As a result I attempted to copy the webconfigs from the main application to the module but I still had a lot of errors.

---

**Update** 6/12/12

After fixing the implementation of RazorBuildProvider to handle modules the app can now successfully render strongly typed views. However the intellisense still renders these errors. I suspect the first error on the `@module...` line is the culprit and is preventing the editor from loading the required information for the strongly typed model.

---

**Update** 6/12/12

Via a process of elimination I've figured out that ninject's PreApplicationStartMethod is the culprit. When the method calls RegisterServices my moduleloader is called and an error is thrown somewhere in there. `[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Frontline.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]`

For a better solution i need to figure out how to debug this error properly, I couldn't find anything so I've posted another (more generic) question on SO [Debugging Visual Studio editor exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735362/debugging-editor-exceptions-error-thrown-by-the-invocation)

I'll also post my hacky fix as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't been able to solve the root of the problem but i have a quick fix.

I'm killing the process during my module loading method if it has visual studio in the name:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.Contains("VisualStudio"))
   return;
```